# Area bounded by $2 \leq|x+3 y|+|x-y| \leq 4$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, inequality, area, absolute-value

> Find the area of the region bounded by $$2 \leq|x+3 y|+|x-y| \leq 4$$

I tried taking four cases which are:
$$x+3y \geq 0, x-y \geq 0$$
$$x+3y \geq 0, x-y \leq 0$$
$$x+3y \leq 0, x-y \geq 0$$
$$x+3y \leq 0, x-y \leq 0$$
But it becomes so confusing to draw the region. Any better way ?

Comment: By triangle inequality we get $|y|\le 1$

Comment: $f(x)=k$ is a growing trapeze, so the resulting area while be a "trapezoidal ring" https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dl30r7krfn

Comment: It's cheating, but you could just stick it into Wolfram Alpha:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=draw+2%E2%89%A4%7Cx%2B3y%7C%2B%7Cx-y%7C%E2%89%A44

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transformation
$$ 
\begin{align}
u &= x + y \\
v &= 2y
\end{align}
$$
transforms the region
$$
2 \leq|x+3 y|+|x-y| \leq 4
$$
to
$$
 2 \leq|u+v|+|u-v| \leq 4
$$
and increases the area by a factor of two (why?). The new region is limited by two squares with side length $2$ and $4$, respectively (compare [How to solve $|a+b|+|a-b|=c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183077/how-to-solve-aba-b-c)),  so that its area can be computed easily.

Comment: I like this answer. I knew there was a linear algebra interpretation.

Comment: why the area is scaled by factor of $2$. ?

Comment: @Umeshshankar: It is a [shear mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping) $(x, y) \mapsto(x+y, y)$ which preserves the area, followed by scaling in $y$-direction by a factor of $2$. Or you use that it is a linear transformation whose determinant is equal to $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would resolve the absolute equations.

$2 \leq|x+3 y|+|x-y| \leq 4$

If $x \geq y,$

$2 \leq|x+3 y|+ x-y \leq 4$

For $x+3y \geq 0, x+3y \leq 0,$ we get

$1 \leq x+y \leq 2, - 1 \leq y \leq -\frac{1}{2}$

Similarly for $x \leq y$, we have

$-2 \leq x+y \leq -1, \frac{1}{2} \leq y \leq 1$

That gives you the below region to find area of,

[image]

Finding area may be easier with a transformation and the transformation choice is obvious but given the focus of the question, I am not getting there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're looking for a plot:

[image]

Now, if we want to find the area of the part where $y\ge0$ and $x\ge0$, we can take a look at the following picture:

[image]

We can find the shaded area by finding:

$$3\cdot\left(\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\left(1-x\right)\space\text{d}x-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\int_1^2\left(2-x\right)\space\text{d}x=\frac{9}{8}\tag1$$

And the place where $y\ge0$ and $x\le0$, we can take a look at the following picture:

[image]

We can find the shaded area by finding:

$$3\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot1+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\left(1-x\right)\space\text{d}x-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{15}{8}\tag 2$$

So, the total area is given by:

$$\mathscr{A}=2\cdot\frac{9}{8}+2\cdot\frac{15}{8}=6\tag3$$